# While practicing a program in python that basically finds all the prime multiples of any number, I got stuck here in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

```py
def prime_no(n):
    num = 0
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            num += 1
    if num == 1:
        return True
    if num > 1:
        return False

def factor_finder(n):
    fact = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            if prime_no(i):
                fact.append(i)
    return fact


def final_factor_finder(n):
    mul =1 
    fact_l = factor_finder(n)
    for i in fact_l:
        mul = mul * i
    val = int(n/mul)
    if val == 1:
        return fact_l
    elif prime_no(val):
        fact_l.append(val)
        return fact_l
    else:
        while val != 1:
            mul =1
            fact_l = fact_l + factor_finder(val)
            for i in fact_l:
                mul = mul * i
            val = int(n/mul)
        return fact_l
```

I got a problem in the `final_factor_finder` function and it happens to be stuck in a `while` loop and do not give any error or results just keeps loading..

I have checked the program multiple times but still stuck with this problem..

Code with the problem. Stuck in the `while` loop:

```py
 while val != 1:
            mul =1
            fact_l = fact_l + factor_finder(val)
            for i in fact_l:
                mul = mul * i
            val = int(n/mul)
        return fact_l
```

When I call `final_factor_finder(16)`, I expect to get a result `[2,2,2,2]` but instead the program gets stuck in the `while` loop and never seems to break out of it in any case.

But when I call the function `final_factor_finder(6)` I get the correct results `[3,2]` as the `else` statement never executes and even the `while` loop. So definitely problem is there in the `while` loop at the end of the program.

```py
 while val != 1:
            mul =1
            fact_l = fact_l + factor_finder(val)
            for i in fact_l:
                mul = mul * i
            val = int(n/mul)
        return fact_l
```

Thanks if anyone would help!

Comment: Did you check what `val` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong assumption you made here is in `range(1, n)`. Range is including to excluding. I.e. from 1 (including) to n (excluding n). E.g. range(1, 3): [1, 2]. This means that if you want to know the factor's of a prime number you will always get an empty list. That's why you final_factor_finder will always get stuck on a 'val' for a prime number. You can fix this with `range(1, n+1)`.

Comment: Thank you bro.HOW I MISSED IT!